# MySQL + PHP ensure unique username (auto increment suffix)

Tags: mysql, unique

Hi i am looking for the most performant way to ensure a unique username.
I did already check similar questions but none of them made me happy.
So here I came up with my solution. I appreciate your comments.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
`guid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`firstname` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`unique_username` varchar(128) NOT NULL,


PRIMARY KEY (`guid`),
KEY `firstname` (`firstname`),
KEY `lastname` (`lastname`),
KEY `username` (`username`),
UNIQUE KEY `unique_username` (`unique_username`),
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)


) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`username` contains  `firstname.lastname` without numeric suffix while `unique_username` contains `firstname.lastname.(count of equal usernames)`

to get the count of equal usernames I am performing following query against the user table (in advance to the insert).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username = 'username'
```

Unfortunately I can't use a lookup against `firstname and lastname` since they are case sensitive.

Comment: How about timestamp (yyyyMMddhhss) + lastname for unique username instead?

Comment: Thank you. I prefer the Facebook way (adding a number to the end). Since the username can be found up in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs say](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html) “nonbinary strings (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT), string searches use the collation of the comparison operands… nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default”, so you should be able to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE CONCAT_WS('.', `firstname`, `lastname`) = 'username`
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my query to: `select count(*) as 'count' from user where  firstname = '$firstname' and lastname = '$lastname'` and it works. What about performance e.g. 1 Million rows?

Comment: `firstname` and `lastname` are both keys, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the case sensitivity you can use LCASE(column) to compare lower case values:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user 
WHERE LCASE(lastname) = LCASE('Lastname') 
  AND LCASE(firstname) = LCASE('firstName');
```

You could also use LIKE to check the username field:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE username LIKE 'username%';
```

That way 'this.name', 'this.name.1' and 'this.name.2' would all get counted together.

I think both of these solutions will not let the optimizer take advantage of the indexes, so the performance might go down, but might be a non-issue.

Comment: Thank you. I guess using LCASE is really going to have an impact to the performance. But Honore Doktorr solution is solving that lowercase problem anyway.